# Displaying a location on a map without using Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have been given this exercise before a job interview to create a small app.
At some point in the app, I need to display a location on a map using latitude and longitude coordinates.

But I think I'm not supposed to use the Google Maps API but rather the "built-in" map on the device.

Is there such a thing?
Is there a simple MapView view I can put in my layout that accepts lat and lon coords and places a marker in the right spot?

I've been searching for a tutorial that explains how to use the built-in maps API on Android but couldn't find one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often times with these code challenge interview they want to see what it is that you can come up with within a relatively short amount of time.

Similarily to what @bwegs had mentioned, you should check with the interviewer as to whether or not there are any restrictions. I have done many interviews where the code challenge would be to create something within 24 hours, but the size of the application is just to large to complete. In cases like this I would utilize third party libraries.

I dont know any other method of retrieving maps so if you can use Google Maps API, than I would start by reading the documentation here  https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Also you may be able to take advantage of Google Static Maps API https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/ which would return a static image of the specific location.

Here is a general AsyncTask that I created to get a Google Static Map

```
class CreateStaticMapAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private static final String STATIC_MAPS_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap";
    private static final String STATIC_MAPS_API_SIZE = "500x500";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        addTask(); // adds one to task count.
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        locationString = params[0];
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(STATIC_MAPS_API_BASE);
        try {
            sb.append("?center=").append(
                    URLEncoder.encode(locationString, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        sb.append("&size=" + STATIC_MAPS_API_SIZE);
        sb.append("&key=" + API_KEY);
        String url = new String(sb.toString());
        Log.e("URL", sb.toString());

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = httpclient.execute(request).getEntity().getContent();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmp;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bmp) {
        super.onPostExecute(bmp);
        if (bmp != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            data = stream.toByteArray();
            removeTask();
            allTasksComplete();

        }
    }
}
```

which can be accessed with this call `new CreateStaticMapAsyncTask().execute(loc);`

and you can retrieve your current location for example, like this (Not the only way)

```
LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            boolean network_enabled = locManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            Location location;

            if (network_enabled) {
                location = locManager
                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                if (location != null) {

                    _longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    _latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    etLocation.setText(_latitude + "," + _longitude);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks ItzHoudini. I think I'll use the Google Maps API then. It's a beginner's position so I guess they want me to use the standard approach. I just thought there was another popular way of doing this.

Comment: I understand from the guide in the link you provided, that I have to register my app to get an API key to use the Google Maps API. But I'm not even publishing the app. It's just an exercise. Is this really the only option?

Comment: I believe you must use an API Key unfortunately. Google Maps API V3 does not require a key, but it is only for Javascript. You should look into how to retrieve your SHA1 fingerprint, and set up a Google Developer Console account. It will take a little time to understand what you are looking at, but its worthwhile because you will encounter several Google API's in your career.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays the "built-in" map on an Android device *is* Google Maps. After all, Android = Google. I can't imagine why anyone would try to make you do this **without** some sort of API but that's another story.

> Don't be afraid to verify with the interviewer (or whoever gave you this exercise) whether or not you can use the Google Maps API - this is kind of an important detail that could make your life a whole lot easier.